# Populating nullable type from SqlDataReader using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection, sqldatareader, reflection.emit

When trying to set value for any nullable datatype using reflection.emit, the values for nullable data types are not populated.

for e.g.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get;set;}
    public string? Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime? Joined {get;set;}
    public bool? IsManager {get;set;}
}
```

Here are my reflection.emit code to populate sql data reader:

```
        private static readonly MethodInfo GetValueMethod = typeof(SqlDataReader).GetMethod("get_Item", new Type[] { typeof(int) });
        private static readonly MethodInfo IsDBNullMethod = typeof(SqlDataReader).GetMethod("IsDBNull", new Type[] { typeof(int) }); 

        DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("DynamicCreateMapping", typeof(T), new Type[] { typeof(IDataRecord) }, typeof(T), true);
        ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

        LocalBuilder result = generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(T));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, result);

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(reader.GetName(i));
            Label endIfLabel = generator.DefineLabel();

            if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null)
            {
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, IsDBNullMethod);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue, endIfLabel);

                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, GetValueMethod);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, reader.GetFieldType(i));
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, propertyInfo.GetSetMethod());

                generator.MarkLabel(endIfLabel);
            }
        }

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I know the problem exist on the below line but not sure how to fix it:

```
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, reader.GetFieldType(i));
```

I try to set but it failed using:

```
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
```

So how to match the datatype from class and not from the sql data reader?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what went wrong when you used `propertyInfo.PropertyType`?

Comment: The entire list becomes null i.e. no records were returned. I suspecting it may have thrown exception internally. When I try to set as reader.GetFieldType(i), it works fine.. But this fails for Nullable data type as data types retunrned by sqlreader are not nullable..so it dont match the datatype and value and i get null value for that nullable data type field even thought reader has value.

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't think your analysis makes sense; there is no difference at runtime between a boxed value and a boxed nullable value, so it shouldn't matter if the data types returned by the reader are nullable or not.  For instance, you can always unbox a boxed `int` as an `int?`.  Perhaps there's something else going on?  Have you considered generating and saving an assembly and running PEVerify on it?

Comment: I know what you are pointing at. But I'm not able to find the core problem. I'll try your suggestion and check. Also, just to add that its happening mostly for Datetime? data Type only for this field I dont see value populated in list though datareader do have values.

Comment: If `propertyInfo.PropertyType` is a nullable type like `int?` you can't assign an int to it. Hope that makes sense. You have to convert from int to int? first. Right?

Comment: @usr, if i have to do that conversion then what should be the step using Reflection.Emit.

Comment: Look at what the C# compiler does, or ask a new question.

Comment: @usr I thought stack overflow is the place where any problem can be solved and not to just run in circles. Please check the title of this questions and then ask me to raise another question. I've very limited or no knowledge about Reflection.Emit. I'm trying to fix what has been there with the current app.

Comment: Just trying to help you. You can get the answer yourself immediately by looking at the compiler output. If you're unable or unwilling to do that you'll have to wait until someone voluntarily provides an answer.

Comment: @usr - if the `int` is boxed, then it can be unboxed directly to `int?`.  I assume the `GetValueMethod` returns an `object`, so this _should_ be a non-issue.

Comment: @kvb I think the problem is the setter which expects a Nullable<int> and gets an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it after breaking head for quite sometime.
Thanks to the link [[http://tillitsonpaper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/mapping-data-reader-to-object.html][1]](http://tillitsonpaper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/mapping-data-reader-to-object.html%5d%5b1%5d).
I did modified few codes and am pasting it here so that it might help newbie who has very little knowledge of reflection.Emit like me.

I added condition to check for Boolean and Enum types:

```
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum || propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean))
     {
           generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, reader.GetFieldType(i));
     }
     else
     {
         generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, GetConverterMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType));
     }
```

The else part above will handle any type including nullable types, The GetConverterMethod implementation is shown below:

```
        private MethodInfo GetConverterMethod(Type type)
        {
            switch (type.Name.ToUpper())
            {
                case "INT16":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToInt16");
                case "INT32":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToInt32");
                case "INT64":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToInt64");
                case "SINGLE":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToSingle");
                case "BOOLEAN":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToBoolean");
                case "STRING":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToString");
                case "DATETIME":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToDateTime");
                case "DECIMAL":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToDecimal");
                case "DOUBLE":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToDouble");
                case "GUID":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToGuid");
                case "BYTE[]":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToBytes");
                case "BYTE":
                    return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToByte");
                case "NULLABLE`1":
                    {
                        if (type == typeof(DateTime?))
                        {
                            return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToDateTimeNull");
                        }
                        else if (type == typeof(Int32?))
                        {
                            return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToInt32Null");
                        }
                        else if (type == typeof(Boolean?))
                        {
                            return CreateConverterMethodInfo("ToBooleanNull");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private MethodInfo CreateConverterMethodInfo(string method)
        {
            return typeof(Converter).GetMethod(method, new Type[] { typeof(object) });
        }
```

The Converter Class code is below:

```
    public class Converter
    {
        public static Int16 ToInt16(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Int16>(value);
        }

        public static Int32 ToInt32(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Int32>(value);
        }

        public static Int64 ToInt64(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Int64>(value);
        }

        public static Single ToSingle(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Single>(value);
        }

        public static Boolean ToBoolean(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Boolean>(value);
        }

        public static System.String ToString(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<System.String>(value);
        }

        public static DateTime ToDateTime(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<DateTime>(value);
        }

        public static Decimal ToDecimal(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Decimal>(value);
        }

        public static Double ToDouble(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Double>(value);
        }

        public static Guid ToGuid(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Guid>(value);
        }

        public static Byte ToByte(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Byte>(value);
        }

        public static Byte[] ToBytes(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Byte[]>(value);
        }
        public static DateTime? ToDateTimeNull(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<DateTime?>(value);
        }

        public static System.Int32? ToInt32Null(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Int32?>(value);
        }

        public static Boolean? ToBooleanNull(object value)
        {
            return ChangeType<Boolean?>(value);
        }

        private static T ChangeType<T>(object value)
        {
            var t = typeof(T);

            if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return default(T);
                }

                t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t); ;
            }

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
        }
    }
```

Might not be very elegant way of doing but this works for any nullable types as well.
Hope this helps to someone who is struggling to get Nullable types working with Reflection.Emit.